# What is defualt Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) CHARACTER SET AND COLLATION Type?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, data-migration, amazon-aurora

> We were used **mysql Version (5.6.19-log)**, we migrate our database
>   from mysql to Amazon RDS.   Mysql table_schema **collation Type -->
>   utf8_unicode_ci**
>
> Mysql table_schema **character Set  --> utf8**
>
> We have done same configuration on Amazon RDS,  Migrate table_schema
>   from mysql to Amazon RDS.
>
> Some tables Varchar type column missed the data in  Amazon RDS
>   database.
>
> I have checked these varchar type column collation is
>   '**latin1_swedish_ci**' and character set type is '**latin1**'

How to resolved these data missing issue??